# Paket + FAKE + swapping dependencies in CI tool

Tags: f#, continuous-integration, f#-fake, paket

I'm messing about with some FAKE and Paket (on F#) and Jenkins, not really sure I know what I'm doing but I know what I WANT to do.

The short description is I want the build server to build a whole family of related services against a referenced package, but the package comes in different flavours (but share the same basic namespace/module names).

The long description;
I have a family of family of services that sit on top of an external 
API.
i.e.
they all are reference some external package and access it through modules etc.

e.g.

```
ServiceA.fsprj

...

let f (x : ExternalApi.Foo) = ....

---------------

ServiceB.fsprj

...

let g (x : ExternalApi.Foo) = ....
```

The developer will probably develop against the most common flavour, lets say ExternalApiVanilla.
The developer will be using Paket, and Fake for build tools, and Jenkins.

When the code is checked in though I want the build service to attempt to build it against the vanilla flavour...but also against chocolate, strawberry and banana.

The flavours are not "versions" in the sense of a version number, they are distinct products, with their own nuget packages. So I think (somehow) I want to parametise a jenkins folder with all the jobs in with the name of the api package, pass that into the build script and then get the build script to swap out whatever the engineer has referenced and reference the parameter.

Of course some compilations will fail, we have to develop different variants of services to handle some of the variants of API, but 90% of our stuff works on all versions, we just need an automated way to check the build and then create new variants of services and jobs, to handle them.

---

as an aside, we are doing some things with C# and cake/nuget, but controlling the versioning by passing the nuget folder in and forcing the build to find specific versions of 1 flavour...I understadn this, though I wouldnt be able to write it, but I want to go 1 step further and replace the reference itself with a different one.

——————-

i’ll try looking at the paket.dependencies/paket references files in the build script, remove the existing reference, and add the jenkins defined ones from a shell and paket and aee what happens, dont especially like it, im dependent on the format of these files and i was hoping this would be mainstream

Comment: Have you considered having several different project files?

Comment: yes...but that would require duplication 100+ projects to add a reference to something, when that almost always is unnecessary

Comment: if I had 100 projects, and 5 different flavours, Id end up with 500 projects, when I only really need about 150

Comment: I think if you have a hundred projects all building together, you have bigger problems.

Comment: ? i dont think this is especially odd...i wouldnt claim the emporers new clothes of microservices, but this sort of architecture is quite commonplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, at least in the context of cake + nuget (and the same solution will apply), by simply search replacing the package reference (using XDocument) in the cake script with a reference parameter set up in the job parameters.

I'll now implement it in the fake version of this build, though I may simply drop paket all
together.